# How to check if a file exists inside a zipped folder with subfolders in python?

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I am trying to write csv file into zipped folder.To avoid duplicates, I want to check is that file already exists in the zipped folder.When we rerun the program, I get duplicate files instead of File already exists

```py
FileName=E:\FOlder1\...\..\..\abc.csv
zipObject = zipfile.ZipFile('E:\Name.zip', 'a')  
if os.path.exists('E:\\Name.zip\\'+FileName[3:]) == False:  
   zipObject.write(FileName)  
   zipObject.close()  

 else:  

   print('File already zipped!')
```

Comment: are you getting an error? Or what's your question/problem?

Comment: I get duplicate files when I rerun the program.it doesn't run else statement.